# Tool to creating SOAP message in PHP

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

Is the any tool to creating SOAP request/response in PHP.

I pass WSDL document and I receive sample SOAP message (like in soapUI) based on this documnet, for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:ns1="urn:flickr" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
....
```

Comment: You mean you're looking for something like [`SoapClient`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php) or any of the other [extensions/classes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php)? Or something [out of a framework](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.soap.html)?

Comment: I have WSDL document, and I want parse this document to get all SOAP request/responses for methods without sending any requests.

Comment: `$client = new SoapClient($wsdlUrlOrPath, array('login' => 'username', 'password' => 'yourPasswordHere');` then: `$response = $client->someSoapCall(array('of' => 'params'));`, finally: `return $response;`. Just spend 5 minutes on google, or try [reading the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php), for a change

Comment: This is not my case. I wont sending any request I only want parse WSDL to get SOAP message (in XML).

Comment: Can you not parse the wsdl doc as you would any other XML document using [xml parser](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php)? Also may i ask why you want to do what you want instead of using SoapClient?

Comment: I can't see what the point of that would be... SOAP UI is what you use to test, PHP is what you _can_ use to perform requests. Anyway: [here's a couple of tools](http://www.mehtanirav.com/2009/01/28/wsdl-to-php-generate-php-code-from-a-wsdl-file/) that might be what you're looking for

Comment: I want this to create examples soap request for methods in my application so I wont use SoapClient. Of course I can mock SoapClient and make fake request only for get generated soap xml request, but this is poorly approach

Comment: Are you building an application like soapUI or you just want to test your APIs?

Comment: I just want to generate XML with request and response to each method in WSDL, this will allow to check is customer request is correct if he compare with my example.

Comment: If thats all you want to do go with soapUI its free or if you have the money go with xmlspy it has an option to generate a request/response xml(they call it sample xml) or if you have the time, write a program that does all that you want and release it to the public.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have imported the WSDL in SoapUI, you will get the requet xml automatically for a SOAP web service. For REST web Services we use XSDs for generating Request XMLs. And for generating xml from an XSD you can use Eclipse.

Comment: I know how I must do it in soapUI, I search tool for PHP which generate request/response from WSDL. Read the title :)

Comment: In tat case you can use the in built feature of SoapUI i.e, groovy scripting for parsing the XML document. Groovy provides XMLSlurper for it. [link]http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/util/XmlSlurper.html. Not sure abt PHP. :(

Comment: This tool is for Java I need for PHP.

Comment: Simple XML ---> http://in3.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples.php does this helps?

Comment: I looking for tool, I wont write this.